# Cross domain communication between iframe and content window without refreshing the iframe window

Tags: iframe, dns, communication

i am currently working on a project where i have to use iframe . how do I achieve cross domain communication (i.e. between content window and iframe) ? 
i am using asp.net. Also each time i try to send a message using parent.postMessage() the iframe seems to be  refreshing and i am able to see message for fraction of second. How to stop it from refreshing?